# Spring placeholder not resolved

Tags: spring

I am declaring properties in applicationcontext.xml and passing external.conf as jvm argument. I am able to read the values in properties file without an issue.

`<util:properties id="hbaseProperties" location="file:///${external.conf}/props/hbase.properties"></util:properties>`

If i add key in property file as below, it fails to resolve the external conf and its getting printed as ${external.conf}/hdfs-site.xml

`site_xml = ${external.conf}/hdfs-site.xml`

I am not sure why this is not getting resolved. What should be done to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your applicationcontext.xml following code snippet

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="<pathToYourPropertyFile>/external.conf"/>
```

For more information about the property placeholder mechanism look at the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors)